# Does Cloud Data Fusion have a connector for Adabas mainframe?

Tags: database-connection, mainframe, google-cloud-data-fusion, adabas

The Google Cloud Data Fusion documentation mentions that the service is capable of connecting to mainframes. Does it have a connector to Adabas Database specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now CDF/CDAP does not support Adabas Database. If you are interested in contributing we would be more than happy to work with you. Examples [here](https://github.com/data-integrations) to get started.